# Geometry, rain gauge problem.

Tags: geometry

Suppose that you have a bowl whose surface can be modelled as a circular paraboloid with $a=b=1$ that you wish to calibrate into a rain gauge. What height is the bowl that would correspond to $1in$ of rain?

Answer (score 1):

What is the $a$ and $b$ in your question? Is it $z=\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}$ So that with $a=b=1$ you have $z=x^2+y^2$? Makes sense, but please clarify if this is not what you meant.

You need to know from what area the device will collect rain. An ideal paraboloid (described by the formula we just discussed) would extend infinitely, and hence collect “all” the rain, having it stream down its walls and towards the apex. Unless you take into account that depending on the height of the cloud layer some clouds might be next to the bowl instead of inside it. Not useful.

Most likely you have the tip of a paraboloid cut off at some plane perpendicular to the axis. So you have a circular surface from which water is collected and led towards the apex. That curcular area times the height of the rainfall ($1\,\text{in}$ in your case) is the volume of rain collected in your device. That volume in turn corresponds to a given height.

To find the relationship between height and volume I'd suggest integrating along the height, but you could also have a look at the formilas in [Wikipedia: Paraboloid § Dimensions of a paraboloidal dish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraboloid#Dimensions_of_a_paraboloidal_dish).

Or you could be trying to have the bowl overflow exactly after $1\,\text{in}$ of rain, with $a=b=1\,\text{in}$ so that we can drop the units. In that case the area of the opening would not be predefined, but instead a function of the height. More specifically $A=\pi r^2$ with $z=x^2+y^2=r^2$ so $A=\pi z$ would be the opening. Now you want the volume in the bowl to equal the volume of rain collected by the opening:

\begin{align*}
\int_0^z\pi t\,\mathrm dt &= A\cdot 1 \\
\frac\pi2z^2 &= \pi z \\
z &= 2
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming axes in inches and not dimensionless)

The gauge will catch all rain above it, so 1 in of rain will be a cylinder with volume
$$
\pi(1)^2(1)=\pi
$$
The volume of a paraboloid of revolution is $\frac{\pi}{2}hr^2$. Plug in the radius and solve for the height:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{2}h(1)^2&=\pi\\
\pi h&=2\pi\\
h&=2
\end{align}
$$
The bowl has height of 2 inches.

Answer (score 0):

Let the paraboloid of revolution have the equation
$$ a z = r^2 ; @ r= R, z=H ; a H = R^2\tag1 $$
$$ dV = \pi r^2 dz; V = \pi \int r^2\, dz= \pi a \,z\, dz = \pi a z^2/2 + const\tag2$$
when evaluated between $z$ limits $(0,H)$ 
$$ V_{paraboloid}= \pi a H^2/2 \tag3 $$
Plug in for $a$ from 1) to eliminate constant $a$
$$ V_{paraboloid}= \pi/2 \cdot H^2  (R^2/H) = \pi/2 \cdot R^2 H \tag4 $$
Rain is measured by water depth in a cylindrical container
$$ V_{cylindrical}= \pi R^2H \tag5 $$
Thus actuall guaged rainfall reported should be *always double* of what is observed in a paraboloidal container... in this case $\, 2 ^{"}.$